# MS CRM 2013 - Opportunity Product

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

For an opportunity when users are entering a second record in line item, I should not let them create second line item if the Product Id are different for those line items.

I am assuming this can be done by web resources(Javascript/xrmscript).

But I am stuck at how to get "Product Id" of first Line Item for an opportunity, when second line item is being entered and before saving the second line item. Sample code / Ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible using JavaScript.  The action calls are rather limited.  I would advise to rather use Visual Studio to develop a plugin.  You will have a lot more control on when the plugin should be triggered.